# Ghosting first day of work

Tags: job-offer

How bad it is to not show up for the first day of work?  I just didn't have a courage to tell my new employer that I found a better offer at last moment, and I will not be joining them.

Today was supposed to be my first day, and I didn't show up. I turned off my phone.

Is it too late to call them and say that I won't be joining them, or would it be better not to contact them at all at this point?

I know I did a terrible thing, and blame myself.

Comment: If you signed a contract, it could be bad, even very bad. If you didn't, it could still be extremely damaging to your career. Have you signed a contract? Does that contract regulate a probation period?

Comment: @Roland no, i haven't signed anything yet. Just accepted offer via email

Comment: That would still constitute a contract. What does the offer say about probation? In any case, you must contact the company or you could face legal consequences.

Comment: We had a similar situation in my former company, the person did not show up. He applied in the same industry in the same city. While the other company was a competitor, everyone knew each other. Long story short: they did not keep the person after the probation period.

Comment: A meta question to the downvoters: Did you downvote because the OP made a bad thing or because it's just a bad question? IMO (but could be convinced otherwise) the question is good and it can be a good resource for others to understand *why* the OP behaviour was very bad (for most it's obvious, but it might not be for everybody).

Comment: @nicola I didn't downvote, but this isn't a useful question for TWP in my opinion. the author knows what they did was wrong, they know what they should do, and seems like they just want us to help them work up the courage to do the right thing. I empathize--I'm pretty sure almost everyone has done something they regretted and hoped that by ignoring the situation it would go away. It usually just results in a lot of stress that's much worse and longer lived than the embarrassment of admitting what you did and accepting the consequences.

Comment: @nicola this reads as a validation post to me - OP knows what they did was bad, knows what to do and needs moral support. While I empathize with them, this is not useful for TWP - it reads more like a TIFU post

Comment: @ColleenV That's fair. I agree that OP's intention, very likely, is hoping to find someone saying that what they did is not that terrible. Nonetheless, given also the quality of the answers, this question does not deserve a downvote, but that's just my opinion and perfectly understand your point of view.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, don't expect to work for this company again in the future and also keep in mind that unprofessional behavior such as this has a way of coming back to bite you.  The people you screwed with may end up being coworkers or even management at some point.

That being said, the most professional thing left to do is to immediately contact the company and let them know that you are not going to be coming to work for them.  This will allow them to change their plans and perhaps extend an offer to another candidate.

Comment: thank you for reply! may i ask was it better to let them know the day before joining them

Comment: The best approach is to let them know as soon as you knew you weren't going to report for work.  So the moment you accepted the other offer you should have contact the first company and let them know.  Waiting until the day after you were supposed to start, or just ignoring them, is incredibly poor behavior.  Don't put yourself in this position again in the future!

Answer (score 7):

You didn't ghost a company, you ghosted people, and you wasted time and resources.

Contact them immediately and tell them the truth, that you won't be coming on board.  It's too late to save your chances of ever working for that company again, but you might be able to salvage a bit of your reputation, not much but some.

Here's why you should contact them.
you have likely already been entered into HR's systems, meaning

- The budget for your position has been closed, they can't hire someone until they know what happened to you (or figure it out for themselves).
- The hiring process needs to start all over again, and people are having to deal with a delay by doing more work
- System resources have been allocated, user ID's assigned, and accounts activated.  They all need to be deallocated.
- Literally DAYS have been spent trying to get you set up, and it's probably still in the process, taking up hours of people's time

and much much more.

There is also the human element.  The human thing is to assume the worst.  If someone didn't show up to the job, I'd be worried that something happened to them

Do the decent thing and let them know.  You'll take some heat and you deserve to but it is the adult, and professional thing to do.

At least they can start the hiring process going and remove you from the system.

Answer (score 2):

Like jwh20 said in their answer: let them know immediately.

Be honest and tell them you will not be joining them and apologize for not showing up on your first day and only letting them know this decision now. Don't make up an excuse (sick/forgot), you do not need to give a reason but if you do, be honest.

I would **strongly** encourage you to learn from this. Think about why you didn't let them know. Were you afraid of confrontation/disappointment? I once called a new employer a day before I was supposed to start because I got an opportunity that I wanted to pursue. They were thankful for letting them know. They do not want a demotivated employee, that sort of resents them for missing out on a great opportunity. The earlier you let them know the better.

Comment: thanks for reply!  yes, i was afraid of conftrontation. Like what if they say "why didn't you tell us earlier, you did a very unethical thing"

Comment: Then what? They are 'just' other people, without any power over you. They have better things to do than to hold a grudge. Say that you know this and you are sorry. Then forget it. You do not have any relationship with them after you decided not to join them. If you want to succeed in the workplace you need to be able to have these kind of confrontations. So you better start learning how to do it, and use this as an opportunity.

Comment: thank you once again! I think learning to have difficult conversation are important skill to have

Comment: It is. I used to hate it. One final thing: you're probably making it much bigger in your head than it is in real life. And the longer you wait, the bigger you make it.

Answer (score 0):

> How bad it is to not show up for the first day of work?

**It's terrible.**  I consider it worse than deciding to stop coming to work after you've started.

Other answers have said why it's a bad idea; I wanted to very specifically answer your question.